# Running Parameters Against an OpenShift Template Through the API

Tags: openshift-origin

I'm developing a custom interface which will integrate with OpenShift Origins. At the moment, I have templates which I wish to instantiate. I know I can do this by running the template against the `/processtemplate` end-point. However, the only way I can find for setting the template parameters is to iterate through the parameter list and overwrite the fields manually.

Is it possible to send a parameter list, and have OpenShift run it against the template, or is this the only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not have something like that today - it might be exposed in the future via a /templates/foo/process endpoint supporting form post, but we were hesitant in case we wanted to expose more complicated parameter values in the future.